# What does the -> operator in TCL do in general and with regexp in specific?

Tags: tcl

Here is the code excerpt:

```
#
# search the header for the base addresses of my slaves and other interesting properties
#
puts ""
puts "Searching \"$system_header_file_path\" for various system information..."

set C_M_N   [ string toupper $console_master_name ]

set sysid_base_re       "^\[ \t\]*#define\[ \t\]+$C_M_N\_SYSID_BASE\[ \t\]+(0x\[0-9a-fA-F\]+)"
set sysid_id_re         "^\[ \t\]*#define\[ \t\]+$C_M_N\_SYSID_ID\[ \t\]+(\[0-9a-fA-F\]+)u"
set sysid_timestamp_re  "^\[ \t\]*#define\[ \t\]+$C_M_N\_SYSID_TIMESTAMP\[ \t\]+(\[0-9a-fA-F\]+)u"
set build_id_base_re    "^\[ \t\]*#define\[ \t\]+$C_M_N\_BUILD_ID_BASE\[ \t\]+(0x\[0-9a-fA-F\]+)"
set gate_base_re        "^\[ \t\]*#define\[ \t\]+$C_M_N\_GATE_BASE\[ \t\]+(0x\[0-9a-fA-F\]+)"
set define_re           "^\[ \t\]*#define\[ \t\]+.*"

set sysid_base              "unknown"
set sysid_id                "unknown"
set sysid_timestamp         "unknown"
set build_id_base           "unknown"
set gate_base               "unknown"

set header_file [ open $system_header_file_path r ]
while { [ gets $header_file next_line ] >= 0 } {
    if { [ regexp $define_re $next_line ] } {
        if { [ regexp $sysid_base_re $next_line -> value ] } {
            set sysid_base              $value
        } elseif { [ regexp $sysid_id_re $next_line -> value ] } {
            set sysid_id                $value
        } elseif { [ regexp $sysid_timestamp_re $next_line -> value ] } {
            set sysid_timestamp         $value
        } elseif { [ regexp $build_id_base_re $next_line -> value ] } {
            set build_id_base           $value
        } elseif { [ regexp $gate_base_re $next_line -> value ] } {
            set gate_base           $value
        }
    }
}
close $header_file
```

I am trying to figure out these things:

File I/O

1. Does the *open* command open the file as text file or binary file? If it opens as text file, how to make it open as binary file instead?
2. How does *gets $header_file* cause next line to be read from file? Is the header_file some sort of file pointer?
3. Why are we checking if the value returned by the gets is >= 0, is there no eof function in TCL?

Regular expressions

1. What is this -> operator being used in the line with the regexp command? As far as I am aware, the regular expression command can be used without this operator as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is 4 different questions in one, so don't be surprised if it ends up being closed as needing more focus. Anyways...

File I/O

1. `open` by default uses text mode, converting to/from a character encoding that's based on your locale. Add `b` to the open mode to open in binary mode, or use `fconfigure $header_file -translation binary` after opening it. Details in the help for [`open`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm).
2. The variable `header_file` holds a symbol that tcl i/o functions translate into an internal file descriptor. The first argument of `gets` is the name of one of these descriptors.
3. `gets` with two arguments returns the number of characters (Or bytes in binary mode) read, or `-1` on an attempt to read when at end of file (Or if there's not a full line available in non-blocking mode). You can have empty lines, which would return 0. If you don't expect to ever encounter a blank line, looping using `>` instead of `>=` might be appropriate; depends on what you're doing. Details in the help for [`gets`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/gets.htm).

Regular expressions:

1. `->` isn't an *operator*, it's a *variable name*. It's just a convention to use it with `regexp` in the argument that is used to hold the entire match when you only care about captured subexpressions.

Comment: You shouldn't use `while {![eof $f]} { gets $f line }` in tcl for the same reasons you [shouldn't do the equivalent in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate the last part please? I was only going to ask the last question but then ending up asking 3 other questions so I don't end up posting two set of questions for the same piece of code.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 See the documentation for [`regexp`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.htm). `->` is even used in one of the examples there. It's just a placeholder for when you don't care about the value being assigned to that variable (Personally, I prefer to use `_`).

Comment: I have seen this example but did not understand why they chose -> which is a symbol and not really a name as such. Basically the -> is used in C and C++ to deference a pointer to struct and access an item inside it. We use it often when working with linked lists and other complex data structures.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 tcl isn't C... (And virtually any string can be used as a variable name in tcl).